# Custom user level throttling with Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions, throttling

I am trying to set API call limits by tier group. Basically a free tier, a paid tier and another paid tier with more limits. I am using Django rest framework and the issue I keep running into is regardless of what tier the user is set at, I still get throttled at the default rate which in this case is 3/minute. Also wondering if there is a way to have a custom response for each tier level rather than the default throttle response. These are dummy numbers I'm using for testing. Herre is my code

throttling.py

```
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class TierBasedRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        user = request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user.tier_level == 'tier_1':
                self.rate = '4/minute'  # Rate limit for tier 1 users
            elif user.tier_level == 'tier_2':
                self.rate = '6/minute'  # Rate limit for tier 2 users
            elif user.tier_level == 'tier_3':
                self.rate = '10/minute'  # Rate limit for tier 3 users

        return super().allow_request(request, view)
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),

# Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
# or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
],
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
],
'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
],
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':[
'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
],
'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
    'accounts.throttling.TierBasedRateThrottle',
],
'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
    'user': '3/minute',
    'tier1': '5/minute',  # Default limit for tier1 users
    'tier2': '10/minute',  # Limit for tier2 users
    'tier3': '15/minute',  # Limit for tier3 users
},
```

finally views.py

```
@api_view(['POST']) 
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, Tier2Permissions))
@throttle_classes([TierBasedRateThrottle])
def LiveSummary(request):
    queryset=liveSummary()
    return Response(queryset)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not setting `self.rate` in `def __init__(self)`, you need to also update `self.num_requests` and `self.duration` using `self.parse_rate(self.rate)`:

```py
from rest_framework.throttling import UserRateThrottle

class TierBasedRateThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    def allow_request(self, request, view):
        user = request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user.tier_level == 'tier_1':
                self.rate = '4/minute'  # Rate limit for tier 1 users
            elif user.tier_level == 'tier_2':
                self.rate = '6/minute'  # Rate limit for tier 2 users
            elif user.tier_level == 'tier_3':
                self.rate = '10/minute'  # Rate limit for tier 3 users

            self.num_requests, self.duration = self.parse_rate(self.rate)  # Add this

        return super().allow_request(request, view)
```